# Jenkins Build disappears in jenkins UI but is present in master machine?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins builds suddenly disappears from the jenkins UI for certain Jobs. The Job triggers and it can been seen in the ui but suddenly vanishes. The build is present in the master machine.

Has anyone faced this before. If so your insights will be really helpful.

We also saw some of our build history being missing when checked in the master all the builds were still present but there was a problem with symlinks being broken in the builds folder for a job

lastFailedbuild, Lastsatblebuild were reset to -1 even though there were some failed builds present.
But this got resolved once a few plugins(disk usage and metrics-diskusage) that were disabled were re-enabled and a reload configuration were done.